# Device tree issue for Hardware GPIO Watchdog in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I have an OrangePi PC Plus board which runs Linux (ubuntu 18.04) with kernel 4.19.57 on Allwinner H3 processor.

We have designed a hardware watchdog using STWD100 ASIC. This IC has a gpio which should be toggled at least once a second, otherwise it resets the board. On the other hand, I have googled on this subject and I realized that Linux kernel has a driver called GPIO watchdog (in *drivers/watchdog/gpio_wdt.c* file).

Because of the project requirement, watchdog GPIO is connected to pin PA19 of processor should begin toggling as soon as the kernel is decompressed and executed, or board is forced reboot by STWD100. For making the issue more complicated, I should add that we can not make any circuit modification. In order to prevent STWD100 from resetting our board before the kernel is loaded, we have a timer which disables STWD100 for about 5~8 seconds and we can not change this time interval (because it is fixed in the circuit). Therefore, we should run our GPIO watchdog driver in Linux kernel as soon as control is passed to the kernel.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Added `printk("============================\n");` to `gpio_wdt_probe()` function of gpio-watchdog driver.
2. Cross-compiled kernel with *CONFIG_GPIO_WATCHDOG=y*, *CONFIG_GPIO_WATCHDOG_ARCH_INITCALL=y*.
3. Decompiled board device tree using `dtc` to get device tree source code from `dtb` file.
4. Modified my device tree source code as follows (according to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/watchdog/gpio-wdt.txt) link):

```dts
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    ...
    soc {
        ...
        pinctrl@1c20800 {
            ...
            phandle = <0x0a>;
            /* Node added by me */
            gpio_wdt: gpio_wdt {                        
                pins = "PA19";
                function = "gpio_out";
                phandle = <0x74>;
            };
            /* Node added by me */
            gpio1: gpio1 {
                gpio-controller;
                #gpio-cells = <2>;
            };
            
        };      
            
        ... 
        /* This node is part of original dts file which triggers internal processor watchdog*/
        watchdog@1c20ca0 {          
            compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-wdt";
            reg = <0x1c20ca0 0x20>;
            interrupts = <0x00 0x19 0x04>;
            phandle = <0x57>;
        };
        ...
    };
    ...
    /* Node added by me */
    watchdog-gpio {
        compatible = "linux,wdt-gpio";
        gpios = <&gpio1 19 1>;          /* PA19 should be toggled */
        hw_algo = "toggle";
        hw_margin_ms = <200>;
        always-running;
        phandle = <0x75>;       
    };
    ...
    __symbols__ {
        ...
        /* Symbol added by me */
        gpiowdt = "/watchdog-gpio";
    };
};
```

In the source `...` depicts some other nodes which I did not modify.

5. compiled modified device tree using `dtc` command.

When kernel runs, I can see `============================` in multiple occasions in kernel logs on UART port. This demonstrates that my builtin GPIO watchdog driver is being probed, but my PA19 pin is not toggling.
In the case above, I do not get any warning from `dtc` compiler, but if I replace `gpio_wdt` instead of `gpio1` in the `watchdog-gpio` node, when compiling device tree I get the following warning from `dtc` compiler:

> *Warning (gpios_property): /watchdog-gpio: Missing property '#gpio-cells' in node /soc/pinctrl@1c20800/gpio_wdt or bad phandle (referred from gpios[0])*

Could anyone help me find the issue?

Comment: I'm puzzled by seeing the `gpio1` node in DTS. If it's production ready device tree it should have GPIO controller defined.

Comment: @0andriy without definition of gpio1, I get this error from dc compiler: _ERROR (phandle_references): /watchdog-gpio: Reference to non-existent node or label "gpio1"_. I don't know what is the problem. I compile device tree on my PC ubuntu (amd64). should I cross compile it? I think device tree does not require cross compilation.

Comment: My point is that the original device tree for the platform must have defined GPIO controller already!

Comment: @0andriy , Thank you. The issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found the solution.

Definition of neither `gpio1` nor `gpio_wdt` would not be useful. I deleted these definitions and modified `gpios` property in `watchdog-gpio` node as follows:

```dts
watchdog-gpio {
        compatible = "linux,wdt-gpio";
        gpios = <0x0a 0 19 1>;          /* PA19 should be toggled */
        hw_algo = "toggle";
        hw_margin_ms = <200>;
        always-running;
        phandle = <0x75>;       
    };
```

where: *0x0a* is phandle of *pinctrl@1c20800* node, 0 corresponds to PortA (for PortC insert 2, for PortD insert 3 and so on), 19 is pin number and 1 corresponds to GPIO flag GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW (flags, that determine active high or active low, pull-up/pull-down resistor connection and so on, are described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt)).